# How to iterate JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, json

Can any one tell me how to iterate below given JSON data using PHP, 
{
"value1":"3",
"value 2":"5",
"Id":[
"210",
"211"
]
}

Comment: try json_decode() function

Comment: Example Code is shown in below <?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

?>

Comment: i was using array also , how could be do this.

Comment: I have answer your question. Let me know if any issues. Could you please explain your needed solution properly that will be helpful to get an immediate solution

Comment: Thank you Mr Sathiaya , i have done it..

Comment: with pleasure :) @parthi

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $json='{ "value1":"3", "value 2":"5", "Id":[ "210", "211" ] }';
$getarr=json_decode($json,true);
foreach( $getarr as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        // ID has an array so retrieve a value
        foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
        {
            echo $key."=>".$value1;  
        }
    }else
    {
    echo $key."=>".$value;  
    }
} ?>
```

It will be produce the below output. Hope it will be helpful to solve your problem

Answer:

`value1=>3 value 2=>5 Id=>210 Id=>211`

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` function for converting it to array.

```
$array = json_decode( $json, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste you can change the print out to fit your use

```
<?php
    $bar=' { "value1":"3", "value 2":"5", "Id":[ "210", "211" ] }';
    //var_dump($bar);
    $JSONdata = json_decode($bar, true);
    //echo
    $JSONdataValue="";
    $JSONdataValue.=$JSONdata['value1']."<br>";
    $JSONdataValue.=$JSONdata['value 2']."<br>";
    $JSONdataValue.=$JSONdata['Id'][0]."<br>";
    $JSONdataValue.=$JSONdata['Id'][1]."<br>";
    echo $JSONdataValue;
    ?>
```